# Lenovo Ideapad S400 laptop won't start after BIOS "update"

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I have "updated" my Lenovo Ideapad S400 BIOS with the Ideapad S300 BIOS, and now my laptop won't start. Even if I plug the charger in, the lights keep turning off and the laptop won't turn on.

So, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Please be informed that no BIOS update is required for this product.
>
> My machine encounters a specific problem, only BIOS update can fix it.
> What do I do next?
>
> Please contact the [Technical
> Support](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/supportphonelist_alt1) for
> further assistance.

Source [BIOS Update](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/ideapad-s400-touch-notebook/downloads/DS100381)